# create adjacency matrix from unique values from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, igraph

I have dataframe shaped like the following:

| country | institution | department | individual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Apple | Marketing | John Fowler |
| UK | Apple | Marketing | Peter Pan |
| China | Apple | Finance | John Fowler |
| Argentina | Bosch | Marketing | Messi |

I would like to create a weighted adjacency matrix that looked like the following:

|  | USA | UK | China | Argentina | Apple | Bosch | Marketing | Finance | John Fowler | Peter Pan | Messi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| UK | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| China | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Argentina | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Apple | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Bosch | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Marketing | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Finance | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| John Fowler | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Peter Pan | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Messi | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I have seen examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806398/create-adjacency-matrix-for-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429594/pandas-dataframe-to-adjacency-matrix) but I could not extend the solutions to more than 2 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator with [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
from itertools import permutations

out = (pd.crosstab(*zip(*((a, b) for l in df.to_numpy().tolist()
                          for a,b in permutations(l, r=2))))
      ).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Output:

```
             Apple  Argentina  Bosch  China  Finance  John Fowler  Marketing  Messi  Peter Pan  UK  USA
Apple            0          0      0      1        1            2          2      0          1   1    1
Argentina        0          0      1      0        0            0          1      1          0   0    0
Bosch            0          1      0      0        0            0          1      1          0   0    0
China            1          0      0      0        1            1          0      0          0   0    0
Finance          1          0      0      1        0            1          0      0          0   0    0
John Fowler      2          0      0      1        1            0          1      0          0   0    1
Marketing        2          1      1      0        0            1          0      1          1   1    1
Messi            0          1      1      0        0            0          1      0          0   0    0
Peter Pan        1          0      0      0        0            0          1      0          0   1    0
UK               1          0      0      0        0            0          1      0          1   0    0
USA              1          0      0      0        0            1          1      0          0   0    0
```

How it works:

- for each row, generate all combinations of 2 items `[(a,b), (b,a), ...]`
- reshape into 2 arrays `[(a,b,...),(b,a,...)]`
- pass the arrays to `crosstab` expanding as the first two parameters

###### corresponding graph:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a little how this works?  I just don't understand the logic but it seems very elegant.

Comment: @JarroVGIT sure, I'll edit the answer

Comment: @JarroVGIT, agree with you, this solution looks really elegant.

Comment: @mozway, I have an error message: "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index." Could you shed light on how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: @Beavis can you provide a reproducible input that triggers the error?

Comment: @mozway I am learning: could you show me an example of a reproducible input?

Comment: @Beavis the reproducible input of the question (which doesn't trigger an error for me): `df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['USA', 'UK', 'China', 'Argentina'], 'institution': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Bosch'], 'department': ['Marketing', 'Marketing', 'Finance', 'Marketing'], 'individual': ['John Fowler', 'Peter Pan', 'John Fowler', 'Messi']})`

Comment: I edited the answer to use permutations, which is better

Comment: @mozway while I was trying the new solution, the error 'repeat' is an invalid keyword argument for permutations(). Is there something else I should be importing?

Comment: @Beavis my fault, I replaced `product` with `permutations`, they (unfortunately) use a different keyword for the repetitions. This is fixed now ;)

Comment: I think my problem is with my dataframe, which I brought in from a csv. I still have this "If you are using all scalar values, you must pass an index." My data frame did not come from a list, but from columns imported from csv. Any clues on how to resolve this?

Comment: Hard to tell without the data, code and debug info. Is this error triggered before my code?

Comment: @mozway I used this trial data (which is a csv file) https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmaaf3kvtgkp1gm/trial_data.csv?dl=0

And then: 
`import pandas as pd`
`import numpy as np`
`df = pd.read_csv("trial_data.csv")`
`from itertools import permutations`
`out = (pd.crosstab(*zip(*((a, b) for l in df.to_numpy().tolist()
                          for a,b in permutations(l, r=2))))
      ).rename_axis(index=None,columns=None)`

Comment: @Beavis I just tried with your file and this worked without issues, what are your python and pandas versions? Can you make sure to use recent versions?

Comment: You are right! I've never had version problems till now. You're a genius. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sliding_window_view` and `networkx` to get a weighted adjacency matrix:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
import networkx as nx

edges = sliding_window_view(df1.values, (len(df1), 2)).reshape(-1, 2)
edges = pd.DataFrame(edges, columns=['source', 'target']).value_counts().reset_index()

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, edge_attr='count')
adjmx = nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G, weight='count').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> adjmx
             Apple  Marketing  Finance  Argentina  Bosch  China  John Fowler  Messi  Peter Pan  UK  USA
Apple            0          2        1          0      0      1            0      0          0   1    1
Marketing        2          0        0          0      1      0            1      1          1   0    0
Finance          1          0        0          0      0      0            1      0          0   0    0
Argentina        0          0        0          0      1      0            0      0          0   0    0
Bosch            0          1        0          1      0      0            0      0          0   0    0
China            1          0        0          0      0      0            0      0          0   0    0
John Fowler      0          1        1          0      0      0            0      0          0   0    0
Messi            0          1        0          0      0      0            0      0          0   0    0
Peter Pan        0          1        0          0      0      0            0      0          0   0    0
UK               1          0        0          0      0      0            0      0          0   0    0
USA              1          0        0          0      0      0            0      0          0   0    0
```

Comment: could you edit your solution? The matrix is unbalanced; individuals are left out of the rows. This looks like a really elegant solution!

Comment: A sliding window view will only show adjacent pairs, not all combinations, this gives an incorrect output :(

Comment: @Beavis. Are you sure you are looking for a (weighted) adjacency matrix?

Comment: @Corralien, yes, a weighted matrix. The output give me rows with repeated row headings.

Comment: How USA could be connected to Marketing if you want an adjacency matrix?

Comment: `networkx` can return a real weighted adjacency matrix. Can you check the output, you will see it's very different of what you expect.

Comment: @Corralien, the code returned an error. 

`G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, edge_attr='count')` 
I changed it to:
`G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, edge_attr=None)`
It ran and it returned a balanced matrix, but unweighted.

Comment: Try with `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, edge_attr=True)`. You need `edge_attr`  to use `count` column as edge attribute to get the weight. Don't forget `.value_counts().reset_index()`?

Comment: Still unweighted :(

Comment: What is your version of `networkx`? `print(nx.__version__)`

Comment: The version is 2.6.3.

Comment: I tested with your version and it works perfectly. Does `edges` dataframe is correct: 3 columns: source, target and count columns?

Comment: I tried your approach again with updated python libraries, but I am still having some issues as it produces a non-weighted matrix. Updated my python to the latest version too. Not sure what's up, but thanks for introducing this method - which gets me inducted into networkx. Cheers

Comment: I hope you will solve this problem. Remember that your expected output is not what is called "a weighted adjacency matrix" :-)